# read.csv blank fields to NA

Tags: r, read.csv

I have tab delimited text file, named 'a.txt'. The D column is empty.

```
 A       B       C    D
10      20     NaN
30              40
40      30      20
20      NA      20
```

I want to have the dataframe looking and acting exactly as the text file, with a space in the 2nd row and in the 2nd column.

Unfortunately, read.csv is converting all the blanks and NA to "NA". I want to read NA and NaN as characters.

```
 b<- read.csv("a.txt",sep="\t", skip =0, header = TRUE, comment.char = "",check.names = FALSE, quote="", )
```

To summarize: I want to replicate the same values in output file without modifying them:

- If there is a blank in input, the output should be blank.
- If the input has NA or Nan, then the output should also have NA or NaN.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After reading the csv file, try the following. It will replace the NA values with "".

```
b[is.na(b)]<-""
```

Fairly certain that won't fix your NaN values. That will need to be resolved in a separate statement

```
b[is.nan(b)]<-""
```

Comment: That will convert all the columns to string variables. The second one, then will not fix `NaN`'s then because all of the columns of `b` will be strings after using the first one.

Comment: This will convert the current NA and NaN values to "".. I wont be able to get them back.. I need to keep NA, NaN and blank values.

Comment: No. It will convert them all to NA.

Answer (score 38):

Late edit: After re-reading this after the edits and extended comments, I'm wondering if what was needed (or asked for, at least) was pretty much the exact opposite of what I advise below. The request for this:

> Unfortunately, read.csv is converting all the blanks and NA to "NA". I want to read NA and NaN as characters.

,,, might have been satisfied (somewhat paradoxically) with the arguments: colClasses="character", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings="."`

Then any character value including an empty string would come in as itself. Arguing against this is the acceptance of the answer that converts empty character values ("") to R `_NA_character` values.

Here's a test example with various results:

```
 sapply(read.csv(text='A\tB\tC\tD\na\t""\tNA\tNaN', sep='\t', na.strings=""), class )
#        A         B         C         D 
# "factor" "logical"  "factor" "numeric" 
 sapply(read.csv(text='A\tB\tC\tD\na\t""\tNA\tNaN', sep='\t', na.strings="x"), class )
#        A         B         C         D 
# "factor" "logical"  "factor" "numeric" 
 sapply(read.csv(text='A\tB\tC\tD\na\t""\tNA\tNaN', sep='\t', na.strings="x", stringsAsFactors=FALSE), class )
#          A           B           C           D 
#"character"   "logical" "character"   "numeric" 

#Almost the expressed desired result
 sapply(read.csv(text='A\tB\tC\tD\na\t""\tNA\tNaN', sep='\t', #colClasses="character", stringsAsFactors=FALSE), class )
#          A           B           C           D 
#"character" "character" "character" "character" 
#But ... still get a real R <NA>
read.csv(text='A\tB\tC\tD\na\t""\tNA\tNaN', sep='\t', colClasses="character", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#  A B    C   D
#1 a   <NA> NaN
#So add all three
 read.csv(text='A\tB\tC\tD\na\t""\tNA\tNaN', sep='\t', colClasses="character", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings=".")
#  A B  C   D
#1 a   NA NaN
# Finally all columns are character and no "real" R NA's
```

---

The default for na.strings is just "NA", so you perhaps need to add "NaN". True blanks ("") are set to missing but spaces (" ") are not:

```
 b<- read.csv("a.txt",  skip =0,  
               comment.char = "",check.names = FALSE, quote="",
               na.strings=c("NA","NaN", " ") )
```

It's not clear that this is the problem since your data example is malformed and does not have commas. That may be the fundamental problem since read.csv does not allow tab-separation. Use `read.delim` or `read.table` if your data has tab-separation.

```
b<- read.table("a.txt", sep="\t" skip =0, header = TRUE, 
               comment.char = "",check.names = FALSE, quote="",
               na.strings=c("NA","NaN", " ") )

# worked example for csv text file connection
 bt <- "A,B,C  
10,20,NaN
30,,40
40,30,20
,NA,20"

 b<- read.csv(text=bt, sep=",", 
                comment.char = "",check.names = FALSE, quote="\"",
                na.strings=c("NA","NaN", " ") )
 b
#--------------
   A  B  C
1 10 20 NA
2 30 NA 40
3 40 30 20
4 NA NA 20
```

Example 2:

```
bt <- "A,B,C,D
10,20,NaN
30,,40
40,30,20
,NA,20"

 b<- read.csv(text=bt, sep=",", 
                comment.char = "",check.names = FALSE, quote="\"",
                na.strings=c("NA","NaN", " ") , colClasses=c(rep("numeric", 3), "logical")) 
 b
#----------------
   A  B  C  D
1 10 20 NA NA
2 30 NA 40 NA
3 40 30 20 NA
4 NA NA 20 NA
> str(b)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A: num  10 30 40 NA
 $ B: num  20 NA 30 NA
 $ C: num  NA 40 20 20
 $ D: logi  NA NA NA NA
```

It's mildly interesting that NA and NaN are not identical for numeric vectors. NaN is returned by operations that have no mathematical meaning (but as noted in the help page you get with `?NaN`, the results of operations may depend on the particular OS. Tests of equality are not appropriate for either NaN or NA. There are specific `is` functions for them:

```
> Inf*0
[1] NaN

> is.nan(c(1,2.2,3,NaN, NA) )
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> is.na(c(1,2.2,3,NaN, NA) )
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  # note the difference
```

Comment: This will convert the current NA and NaN values to "".. I wont be able to get them back.. I need to keep NA, NaN and blank values.

Comment: I dig more into my data...The column D is totally empty ,,with class "logical". \

Comment: How can something be totally empty with class logical? PLEASE POST YOUR DATA. You have not shown us what the teext file looks like and are perhaps showing us what screen output you are seeing.... not the same thing.

Comment: The column D is empty.If you do sapply(b,class).. you get A B C D ""integer" "integer" "numeric" logical"

Comment: You still are not telling us what your data file looks like. I can make an empty logical column if I use colClasses> See above.

Comment: How can I post my file as attachment?

Comment: Open it up in a text editor and paste it into your question. (NOT into a commnet.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38489/discussion-between-user1631306-and-dwin)

Comment: `b<- read.csv("a.txt",  skip =0,  
               comment.char = "",check.names = FALSE, quote="",
               na.strings=c("NA","NaN", " ") )`

The blank fields to be a NA you just need to have the quotes with no spaces. From what I read he wants to keep the NaN separated from NA which is not clear with his question.
`na.strings = c("NA", "NaN", ""))`

Answer (score 5):

Use the **na.string** argument.
**na.string** is used to define what arguments are to be read as na value from the data. So if you mention

```
read.csv(text=bt, na.string = "abc")
```

then whenever in your data it the value "abc" occurs, then it will convert it into na.
Since "abc" is not found in your data it won't convert any value into na.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `colClasses` in the `read.csv` statement to read the column as text.

Comment: This is not correct. `colClasses` doesn't help here. Or maybe more precisely, there is a more appropriate argument to use, I think.

Comment: Very cryptic... `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`?

Comment: I don't understand. When the OP says he/she wants to have the dataframe exactly as the text file, do they mean that we should get three columns with a blank, an "NA", and a "NaN" as three of the entries as shown in the question?

Comment: I agree the OP's question is a bit unclear. My only point was that, as DWin points out, the `na.strings` argument seems a more likely suspect than `colClasses` here.

Comment: What I meant, if I write "b" to nee text file, it should be exactly as the input t.txt,,with spaces...not newly introduced Na

Comment: setting colClasses="character" worked, but it chnages everything to string, even numeric part..which restrict the calculation part

Comment: Lets take a step back, why do you need to treat blanks as different from NAs? If you intend to write out b as a csv then maybe you can keep a copy with all columns read in as text, and have a temporary dataset in which you convert the necessary columns to numeric. As you can see on most of the answers and comments, nobody is sure what exactly you're trying to do. It will help if you make your question more clear.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.. I have the the file, with one column empty, some columns with Na, and NaN. I am doing some calculation on this file and writing it to to new files, adding some columns.. But the empty colummn is not empty there anymore,,its NA..What I want, is exactly same format of file in my output file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't completely understand your problem. This shall be my last response to this question - read all the columns as text into b. Make a copy of b and convert the columns to numeric in this copy. Run your calculations on the copy. If you need to update b before you write it out again, then update specific columns (like b$A <- something), and not the whole dataset (i.e. not b <- something), leaving D untouched. Use write.csv (alongwith the na argument if needed).