# R - remove rows from a data frame with empty lines (not only numbers)

Tags: r, parsing, row

The issue seems to be something already treated but after a check I couldn't find any solution. I load a table from a file and it could be (don't know how) that some entire lines are empty. So when I get the data frame I got

```
  #   id c1 c2
  # 1  a  1  2
  # 2  b  2  4
  # 3    NA NA
  # 4  d  6  1
  # 5  e  7  5
  # 6    NA NA
```

if I do

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))
```

I got all `FALSE` as the first column is not a number (the table is much bigger with mixed character and numeric columns) and I can't filter these lines. Also with `na.omit` or `complete.cases` I cannot sort it out.
Is there any function or expression to check empty rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to cut this problem off at the source with the parameters you pass to `read.csv`:

For instance if the blanks are one space or blanks you could use

```
df <- read.csv(<your other logic here>, na.strings=c("NA","", " ")
```

This question seems to raise similar issues: [read.csv blank fields to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19125899/1594060)

If this works, then you can use the apply logic to work with the offending rows.

Comment: So do the opposite than there and replace black spaces by `NA` and then the apply logic?

Comment: Yeah, for me the linked issue is definitely distinct from yours, however it brings some options such as the na.strings parameter that I believe will solve your problem. Could you post an excerpt of the file that causes the issue, then maybe I can figure out something more specific?

Comment: Actually you are totally right!! using `na.strings` I can set empty data by NA and then I can use the apply function! thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help @Stefano!